# How do I create a caption overlay on the photos in a slide show?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am creating a slide show iPad app.
I have already modified Michael Waterfall's MWPhotoBrowser and it works fine with my photos.

I now want to add captions which appear and disappear at the bottom of each photo whenever the user taps on a photo.

How else shall I proceed?
Any links to point me to the right direction?

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but the current version of MWPhotoBrowser now handles captions and behaves similar to the spec above.  Looks great.